# How do I add a link back to my main webpage from a page written with mkdocs?

Tags: mkdocs

I am building a general website that also has a documentation page. For the docs page I'm using mkdocs. I would like a link in the docs page, ideally in the top right corner, that goes back to my main webpage. I know how to put links inside the docs, but I'd like this to appear like a header. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible at this time. However, this is the subject of issue [#989](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/989) and may be added in the future.